# Experiment with OHSUMED dataset using SVM Rank

Tags: machine-learning, svm, ranking, svmlight

I am trying to learn RankSVM using OHSUMED dataset and SVM Rank library as explained in following link:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-s/um/beijing/projects/letor/Baselines/RankSVM-Struct.txt

I used same parameters as link suggests for OHSUMED dataset. i.e

OHSUMED/QueryLevelNorm/cv_l1_e0.001/fold1_l1_c0.0002_e0.001.log
OHSUMED/QueryLevelNorm/cv_l1_e0.001/fold2_l1_c0.002_e0.001.log
OHSUMED/QueryLevelNorm/cv_l1_e0.001/fold3_l1_c0.01_e0.001.log
OHSUMED/QueryLevelNorm/cv_l1_e0.001/fold4_l1_c0.02_e0.001.log
OHSUMED/QueryLevelNorm/cv_l1_e0.001/fold5_l1_c0.01_e0.001.log

But when I train my model & run "svm_rank_classify" command I get following result:

> Reading model...done.
>   Reading test examples...done.
>   Classifying test examples...done
>   Runtime (without IO) in cpu-seconds: 0.00
>   Average loss on test set: 0.3864
>   **Zero/one-error on test set: 100.00% (0 correct, 22 incorrect, 22 total)**
>   NOTE: The loss reported above is the fraction of swapped pairs averaged over
>         all rankings. The zero/one-error is fraction of perfectly correct
>         rankings!
>   Total Num Swappedpairs  :  31337
>   Avg Swappedpairs Percent:  38.64

Please suggest If any steps I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question some? Are you just asking what the zero/one-error means and why it's not less than 100%? Were you expecting different output?

Answer (score 1):

The zero/one-error is the percentage of rankings (i.e. `qid` sets) where the model ranked at least one pair incorrectly. Your accuracy over all pairs is actually:

```
(100 - Avg Swappedpairs Percent) = 61.36%
```